# How do I switch the direction of the menu drop down when it flows over the width?

Tags: html, css

In our dropdown menu, there are too many columns which tends to overflow to the right, outside of screen bounds:

[image: Menu overflowing]

Can I change the CSS or HTML to rather render the menu to the left if it's outside of screen bounds?

Here's the CSS of the 'Configurations' menu:

```
.dropdown_4columns, .dropdown_5columns {
    margin: 4px auto;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #ccc;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ap8ntctt/

Comment: can you please share link where this menu is working as by only css we cant help.

Comment: @Leothelion I've updated the post with some html and css example that I extracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `margin: 4px auto;` to `margin:4px auto 4px -200px;`

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mk1427q3/

Comment: Easy. `margin: top/bottom left/right` to `margin: top right bottom left`. just set margin-left to -200 px to shift 200px left for 2-col menu and I think you need to shift -500px for 5-col menu for the configuration section in the example

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown is absolute positioned so change left position and make it such that drop down will be centered in this case.`li:hover .dropdown_2columns{left:87;top:auto;}`

https://jsfiddle.net/mk1427q3/5/

Ideally your drop down should not overflow from the view port make it center align if its two big you can refer leading e-commerce sites to check how they manage there big drop downs without overflowing outside.